# How can I get Zurb Foundation 5 to be more mobile friendly on iPhone 5/Galaxy S4

Tags: css, mobile, laravel, zurb-foundation

I'm having trouble getting my layout to be more mobile friendly on high pixel count screens. On iPhone 5 and Galaxy S4 it's showing the medium layout instead of small. I really love Foundation and it's really been helpful, this is just being a hangup for me. The medium layout is so small on appearing on these high pixel count screens that it's not really usable.

The site i'm working on is [mtgdatabase.com](http://mtgdatabase.com). I'm using Laravel with Foundation 5, and the [source code is located here](https://github.com/jshultz/mtgdatabase).

I started with small and worked my way up being sure to follow mobile first.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to adjust your media queries to show for small at a higher pixel density. You can access the media queries and adjust the parameters from the CSS files that you downloaded as part of the Foundation package.

Start here from the Foundation Docs: [Zurb - media queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html)

Comment: apparently I was missing this: "<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">"